# Using Eclipse to run Cucumber tests with Maven is causing multiple Chrome windows to open, and won't close

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, cucumber, hook

hopefully someone can help.

I've got tests written out, but for some reason Chrome launches a blank browser page,  then a second. The second chrome window follows all of the steps, but ignores the After hook to close the browser/delete cookies etc. Basically, the test runs, but I'm left with a mess to clean up after.

How do I get Chrome to stop opening multiple windows and how do I get it to actually close the browser?

Here's the test case:

```
package CucumberFramework.stepsFiles;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;


public class Launchpad_Battery_Search{
        WebDriver driver;
        
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            this.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                     
        }
        @AfterMethod
        public void teardown() {
            this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            this.driver.close();
            this.driver = null; 
        }   
        @Given ("^user logs in$")
        public void user_logs_in() throws Throwable{
            driver.get("https://app.websitebeingtested.com");           
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ObservableObject@20.email\"]")).sendKeys("definitelyabetatester@gmail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ObservableObject@20.password\"]")).sendKeys("BasicPass!23");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign In']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }   
        
        @Given ("^user clicks launchpad icon$")
        public void user_clicks_launchpad_icon() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/agencyLaunchpad']")).click();
        }
        
        @Given ("^user searches launchpad for batteries$")
        public void user_searches_launchpad_for_batteries() throws Throwable {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("batteries");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()= 'Search']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
        @Then ("^search returns applicable results$")
        public void search_returns_applicable_results() throws Throwable {
            WebElement GetAQuote = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Get a Quote')]"));
            AssertJUnit.assertEquals(true, GetAQuote.isDisplayed());
        }
        
}
```

Comment: you hae only this file ? please add the testng xml (or anyother runner you use ) and maven

Comment: @PDHide Sorry, not following. Would those be in the pom?

Comment: how are you running this ?

Comment: I'm using testng and maven like you said, sorry I'm brand new to this so I don't know exactly which part is doing what. Happy to copy paste the files, just not sure which you want to see

Comment: please copy paste

Comment: i don't know where they are to copy paste. I don't know what I'm looking for. I can't find either of those in the file tree. Perhaps I should have set them up before? Would these even run without that?

Comment: Oh- maybe they're running as a junit test?

Answer (score 0):

As you picked up earlier in the comments, you are most likely running this as a JUnit test rather than testng, which is why your framework is not recognizing the @AfterMethod tag.  Since you are using cucumber, (and already using its @Before tag) the simplest way to solve this would be to use the cucumber @After tag instead.

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;

@After
```

your method here.

Additionally, for your particular situation you may be better served to use the driver.quit() method instead of close.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Any idea why chrome opens a blank browser window alongside the one that actually executes the steps?

Comment: I would need to see more of your code to be sure but if I had to guess I would say you have an additional (probably blank) scenario defined in your feature file.